# Required binary date specifications

Tags: date, datetime-format

I want to create a binary date trawler for searching for given dates in binary files where the date format and structure of the binary file are unknown.  Unless there is something out there that already does this.

I'm looking for reference material for the specification of as many binary date specifications as possible.

I know of some date types :

DOS, FILETIME, OLE, ANSI SQL, C, Mac Abs, HFS, APFS, Java

But where can I find the binary specification for these and any other date formats?

Comment: There isn’t a Java binary date format. How to represent a date in a binary file is up to the programmer, and I can think of several reasonable ways. When you say *dates*, is it given that only the date is in the file, or could there be a time part? A time zone or offset?

Comment: yes dates mean date/time!